# Join PySpark ML predictions to identifier data

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm building a classification model using PySpark and its ML library. In my input dataframe, I have an identifier column (called `erp_number`) that I want to exclude from building the model (I don't want it to be a feature of the model), but I want to add it back when the predictions are output.

```
def create_predictions(data, module):

    data = data.drop("erp_number")

    # Identify categorical columns
    categorical_columns = [field.name for field in data.schema.fields if isinstance(field.dataType, StringType)]

    # Numerical columns, excluding the categorical and target columns
    numerical_columns = [field.name for field in data.schema.fields if field.name not in categorical_columns and field.name != module]

    # Create a list of StringIndexers and OneHotEncoders
    stages = []
    for categorical_col in categorical_columns:
        string_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol=categorical_col, outputCol=categorical_col + "_index", handleInvalid="keep")
        encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCols=[string_indexer.getOutputCol()], outputCols=[categorical_col + "_vec"])
        stages += [string_indexer, encoder]

    # Add VectorAssembler to the pipeline stages
    feature_columns = [c + "_vec" for c in categorical_columns] + numerical_columns
    assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=feature_columns, outputCol="features")
    stages += [assembler]

    # Add the GBTClassifier to the pipeline stages
    gbt = GBTClassifier(labelCol=module, featuresCol="features", predictionCol="prediction")
    stages += [gbt]

    # Create a Pipeline
    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)

    # Fit the pipeline to the data
    model = pipeline.fit(data)

    # Apply the model to the data
    predictions = model.transform(data)

    return predictions
```

I tried to drop the column from the dataframe. But it looks like there is no equivalent to pandas concat or dplyr bind_cols.
I tried to exclude the erp_number from the `feature_columns` list, but this generates an error in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the way : you simply have to leave the field in your dataframe, but to not include it in the features of the model. Very handy.
I tried this before but forgot to remove the field from the numerical columns :

```
def create_predictions(data, module):

    # Identify categorical columns (excluding id)
    categorical_columns = [field.name for field in data.schema.fields if isinstance(field.dataType, StringType) and field.name != "erp_number"]

    # Numerical columns, excluding id, categorical and target columns
    numerical_columns = [field.name for field in data.schema.fields if field.name not in categorical_columns and field.name not in [module, "erp_number"]]

    # Create a list of StringIndexers and OneHotEncoders
    stages = []
    for categorical_col in categorical_columns:
        string_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol=categorical_col, outputCol=categorical_col + "_index", handleInvalid="keep")
        encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCols=[string_indexer.getOutputCol()], outputCols=[categorical_col + "_vec"])
        stages += [string_indexer, encoder]

    # Add VectorAssembler to the pipeline stages
    feature_columns = [c + "_vec" for c in categorical_columns] + numerical_columns
    assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=feature_columns, outputCol="features")
    stages += [assembler]

    # Add the GBTClassifier to the pipeline stages
    gbt = GBTClassifier(labelCol=module, featuresCol="features", predictionCol="prediction")
    stages += [gbt]

    # Create a Pipeline
    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)

    # Fit the pipeline to the data
    model = pipeline.fit(data)

    # Apply the model to the data
    predictions = model.transform(data)

    return predictions
```